# Android (Facebook API) - How do I force a call to onComplete(Bundle values)?

Tags: android, facebook, dialog, bundle

I have a facebook dialog in the screen in which I put a button on the top right of the page (next to the Facebook`s login page). What I want to do is, if the user hits that button, dismiss the Facebook Dialog and pass some values for the activity that started the Facebook dialog (that is, the activity who called:

```
  mFacebook.authorize(this, Settings.FACEBOOK_PERMISSIONS, Facebook.FORCE_DIALOG_AUTH, new LoginDialogListener());
```

The problem is that I only know how to dismiss the Facebook dialog WITHOUT BEING ABLE TO PASS ANY PARAMETERS TO IT, because the callback function onCancel() of the DialogListener doesn`t receive a Bundle. I can`t pass parameters back to the original activity (I could if the signature was onCancel(Bundle bundle) ).

In other words, what I want is either something like a onCancel(Bundle bundle) (which, unfortunately, doesn`t exist) or a way to programatically return to the callback onComplete(Bundle values) because, that way, I could read the Bundle values that I had set while the Facebook dialog was on the screen).

Thank you in advance!

### Update (Code)

```
private class LoginDialogListener implements DialogListener {

    public void onComplete(Bundle values) {
        Settings.setFBStats(Settings.getFBStats() + 1);
        facebookPost();
        Util.showThanks(PhotoActivity.this, galleryName);
    }

    public void onFacebookError(FacebookError error) {
    }

    public void onError(DialogError error) {
    }

    public void onCancel() {
        System.out.println("Hi! =D");
    }
}





public void facebook(View target) {
    mFacebook = new Facebook( getString(R.string.facebookappid) );
    mAsyncRunner = new AsyncFacebookRunner(mFacebook);
    mAsyncRunner.logout(this, new LogoutRequestListener());
    mFacebook.authorize(this, Settings.FACEBOOK_PERMISSIONS,    Facebook.FORCE_DIALOG_AUTH, new LoginDialogListener());
}
```

And here is the code inside the FbDialog.java`s onCreate() method:

```
      @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    mSpinner = new ProgressDialog(getContext());
    mSpinner.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    mSpinner.setMessage("Loading...");

    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

    mContent = new FrameLayout(getContext());

    /* Create the 'x' image, but don't add to the mContent layout yet
     * at this point, we only need to know its drawable width and height 
     * to place the webview
     */
    createCrossImage();

    overlay = new ImageView(getContext());
    overlay.setImageDrawable(getContext().getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.overlay_horiz));
    overlay.setTop(0);
    overlay.setLeft(0);
    overlay.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

    /* Now we know 'x' drawable width and height, 
     * layout the webivew and add it the mContent layout
     */
    int crossWidth = mCrossImage.getDrawable().getIntrinsicWidth();
    setUpWebView(crossWidth / 2);


    /* Finally add the 'x' image to the mContent layout and
     * add mContent to the Dialog view
     */

    mContent.addView(mCrossImage, new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

    FrameLayout main = new FrameLayout(getContext());
    main.addView(overlay, new LayoutParams(1280, 755));

    RelativeLayout rel = new RelativeLayout(getContext());

    mContent.setPadding(450, 60, 0, 0);
    rel.addView(mContent, new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));

    closeIt = new ImageButton(getContext());
    closeIt.setBackgroundDrawable(getContext().getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.closefb));

    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(282, 150);
    lp.setMargins(980, 10, 0, 0);

    closeIt.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    closeIt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            mListener.onCancel();
            FbDialog.this.hide();//HERE!!! =D
        }
    });

    rel.addView(closeIt,lp);

    main.addView(rel, new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));

    addContentView(main, new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
}
```

The button that I am talking about is the **closeIt** button.

Do you see the setOnClickListener method of the closeIt button? So, I am only able to dismiss or hide the button. When I do any of that (dismiss or hide), the onCancel() method of the LoginDialogListener is called. The problem is that I cannot detect that it came from that button, because the flow also goes to that very same onCancel() method when the user presses de default X button next to the facebook dialog. If I am able to detect that it came from my button, then I can do some other things I want in the code.

Thank you once again.

Comment: are you able to click a button on activity screen when fb dialog is open ? and also the bundle comes from facebook code, why even you want to edit it ?

Comment: Well, I created a button next to the login screen of Facebook Dialog. I am able to "click" on it, but the most I can do after that is to dismiss the Facebook dialog without passing any parameters to the previous activity (the activity that started the Facebook dialog). All I want is to be able to pass some parameters to the previous activity if the user presses that button, but I can`t find a way to do that.

Comment: Do you have your button on the facebook dialog itself ? if not, you can click the button only after dismiss of the dialog. Also does the previous activity not receive the onCancel() callback ? if yes, then that is an indication that the user has cancelled the dialog.

Comment: Yes, I have my button in the Facebook dialog itself. I put it there programatically, right next to the login fields. So, when the user hits the button, I am able to dismiss the dialog, which makes me go back to the onCancel() method. However, it also enters in the onCancel() method if the user hits the standard `x` button, right in the top corner of the Facebook dialog. I need to be able to differentiate when the user presses that X button or my button, that`s why I need something like an onCancel(Bundle b). That way I would be able to populate the bundle and see if the user pressed my button.

Comment: Could you please post your button related code ? How you are accessing `FBDialog`. One way, you may subclass `DialogListener` (and either define a new function or overload `onCancel()`) and pass it in `authorize()`, and in your `onClickListener` attached to your button, pass the required value(s).

Comment: I have updated my question with the code. Thank you once again Kailash!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `Facebook.DialogListener` class and add a new `onCancel(Bundle)` function to it, (You may also change the existing `onCancel()` to `onCancel(Bundle)`, but this should be avoided to maintain compatibility with the existing code.), then call `onCancel(bundle)` in `onClick()` of `closeIt` button.

OR

if `LoginDialogListener` is accessible in `FbDialog` then define a new function `onCancel(Bundle)` in it (You may use any `Object` instead of `Bundle`). Then in your `onClick()` of `closeIt` button, call

```
closeIt.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            ...initialize_bundle...
            ((LoginDialogListener) mListener).onCancel(bundle);
            FbDialog.this.hide();//HERE!!! =D
        }
    });
```

OR

Define a new subclass of `Facebook.DialogListener`, Lets say it `classA`, having a new `onCancel(Bundle)` function. This `classA` should be visible to `FbDialog`. Now redefine your `LoginDialogListener` so that it is a subclass of `classA`. In your `onClick()` of `closeIt` button, call

```
closeIt.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            ...initialize_bundle...
            ((classA) mListener).onCancel(bundle);
            FbDialog.this.hide();//HERE!!! =D
        }
    });
```

Hope it helps !!

Comment: Hi Kailash, thanks again for replying. I feel like we are getting close to an end! =) But I have a question: how do I call the onCancell(Bundle b) method I will create? It is a callback function, so I don`t know how to call it. The LoginDialogListener private class is in a different .java file then the FbDialog.java.

Comment: Being in a different java file, does not matter unless facebook code is a different project (e.g. a library project). It seems that you are new to Java. If you do want easy solution go with 1st (see my answer) approach, otherwise go with 3rd (the last) approach. Regarding how to call ? I have updated my answer.

Comment: Well, the solution 3 was the way to go, because the Facebook code was in its own project. Thank you Kailash! Sorry for not accepting your question earlier. This week have been crazy in the office and I forgot to do that.